# vertical gap on menu without using jquery

Tags: css

I was wondering how, in this example, it is possible to have a gap between the menu item and the list.

This is the CSS code for the demo

```
#colorNav > ul{
    width: 450px; /* Increase when adding more menu items */
    margin:0 auto;
}

#colorNav > ul > li{ /* will style only the top level li */
    list-style: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2) inset,1px 1px 1px #CCC;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position:relative;
}

#colorNav > ul > li > a{
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    font-size:24px;
    padding: 25px;
}

#colorNav li ul{
    position:absolute;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    width:180px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-90px;
    top:70px;
    font:bold 12px 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;

    /* This is important for the show/hide CSS animation */
    max-height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;

    -webkit-transition:max-height 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition:max-height 0.4s linear;
    transition:max-height 0.4s linear;
}

#colorNav li ul li{
    background-color:#313131;
}

#colorNav li ul li a{
    padding:12px;
    color:#fff !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    display:block;
}

#colorNav li ul li:nth-child(odd){ /* zebra stripes */
    background-color:#363636;
}

#colorNav li ul li:hover{
    background-color:#444;
}

#colorNav li ul li:first-child{
    border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
    margin-top:25px;
    position:relative;
}

#colorNav li ul li:first-child:before{ /* the pointer tip */
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    border:5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color:#313131;
    left:50%;
    top:-10px;
    margin-left:-5px;
}

#colorNav li ul li:last-child{
    border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
}

/* This will trigger the CSS */
/* transition animation on hover */

#colorNav li:hover ul{
    max-height:200px; /* Increase when adding more dropdown items */
}
```

Here is the link: 
http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/10/css3-dropdown-menu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#colorNav li ul li:first-child {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Is what is creating the gap.